# Update EmployeeID Attribute based on csv

Tags: powershell

Here is the code I used to update the employeeID attribute based on csv.
I want to do verify the input value and then return the result of not matching items.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
Import-CSV “C:\PSS\UserList.csv” | % {
$mail = $_.mail
$ID = $_.EmployeeID
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -eq $mail}
Set-ADUser $Users.samaccountname -employeeID $ID
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not matching"? Do you want information about which email addresses wasn't found in the directory? Or information about which accounts already have the correct employeeID vs the ones that need to be updated?

Comment: yes to verify the email addresses wasn't found in the directory

Answer (score 1):

No sense over-complicating it.

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
$failedAccounts = @()
Import-CSV “C:\PSS\UserList.csv” | % {
    $mail = $_.mail
    $ID = $_.EmployeeID
    $users = Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -eq $mail}
    if ($users -ne $null){
        Set-ADUser $Users.samaccountname -employeeID $ID
    }
    else {
        $failedAccounts += $mail
    }
}
Write-Host "Failed Accounts: $($failedAccounts.count)"
$failedAccounts
```

Comment: Is it possible to include logging on it?